# Why lein repl blocks STDERR

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Why lein repl blocks STDERR. I run `lein repl` without project and also `lein repl` or `lein run` with a project and having problems printing to STDERR. For example when connecting to NREPL (different terminal tab) and running:

```
(.println System/err "something")
```

I can see nothing printed in the launching terminal window - only in the repl. How to get STDERR to print in both as it is used for SYSTEMD logging.
I use newest Leiningen and project is generated wit the `app` template.

Comment: odd, here's what I get: lein repl
user=> (.println System/err "bubu")
bubu
nil

Comment: Please add your version of clojure, leiningen, and the contents of your ~/.lein/profiles.clj. FWIW my combination of those things prints fine with the snippet you posted.

Comment: Oh, so your *real* question is about writing to the journal? This is a lot clearer now. I'd start reading through https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider-nrepl/blob/master/src/cider/nrepl/middleware/out.clj, or whatever middleware is actually in use in your stack.

Answer (score 0):

`lein repl` does no such thing. You can test this yourself:

```sh
# stop our individual writes from overlapping
with_lock() { exec {lock_fd}>>./tty_write_lock; flock "$lock_fd"; "$@"; exec {lock_fd}>&-; } 

lein repl 3>&2 \
           > >(while IFS= read -r line; do with_lock printf 'O:<%q>\n' "$line" >&3; done) \
          2> >(while IFS= read -r line; do with_lock printf 'E:[%q]\n' "$line" >&3; done) \
          3>&- <<'EOF'
(.println System/err "something on stderr")
(.println System/out "something on stdout")
EOF
```

...which contains, among other output:

```
O:<$'user=> (.println System/err "something on stderr")\E[50G\E[8G\E[51G'>
E:[something\ on\ stderr]
O:<nil>
O:<$'user=> (.println System/out "something on stdout")\E[50G\E[8G\E[51G'>
O:<something\ on\ stdout>
O:<nil>
```

As you can see, `something on stdout` is inside `O:<...>`, as created by the process substitution handling stdout; whereas `something on stderr` is inside `E:[...]`, as created by the process substitution handling stderr.

---

To look at it a different way:

```sh
{ strace -f -e write lein repl 2>&1 | egrep 'write[(][12],'; } <<'EOF'
(.println System/err "something on stderr")
(.println System/out "something on stdout")
EOF
```

...includes among its output the following syscalls:

```
[pid 10467] write(2, "something on stderr", 19) = 19
[pid 10467] write(1, "something on stdout", 19) = 19
```

...as you can see, the stderr one is correctly written to FD 2, whereas the stdout one is correctly written to FD 1.